# Custom Navigation Menu in Silverstripe

Tags: navigation, silverstripe

I am learning Silverstripe CMS today and have run into a problem I can not find an answer to.

I have a CSS driven drop down menu with three main titles. The titles themselves are not links however the children are.

**The problem I am having is that the way I read it the menu is generated from the page hierarchy. My main menu titles are not pages, so how do I start with that and then put the proper page links under each title?**

I am using this code to generate the menu dynamically

```
<nav class="seven columns u-right-align main-nav">
      <ul style="position: relative; z-index: 10000">
                <% loop $Menu(1) %>
                    <li>$MenuTitle
                     <% if $LinkOrSection == section %>
                        <% if $Children %>
                              <ul>
                                 <% loop $Children %>
                                     <li><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></li>
                                 <% end_loop %>
                             </ul>
                        <% end_if %>
                   <% end_if %>
               </li>
            <% end_loop %>
        </ul>
  </nav>
```

Expected layout...

```
<nav class="seven columns u-right-align main-nav">
    <ul style="position: relative; z-index: 10000">
        <li>About <!--  I do not know where to create this title in SS -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Annual Meeting</a></li>
                <li><a href="">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Society Calendar</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as you don't know where to put the "About" section title - this is not built in SilverStripe by default. You'll have to add a "RedirectorPage" for it and redirect to the first Child instead.

Fortunately others also had this problem and there are [some page types that do the trick for you](https://github.com/purplespider/silverstripe-mypswd-tweaks/blob/master/code/pages/FirstChildRedirect.php).

You can reuse the template you already have.

The page type linked above has funcitonality in Controller's `init()` method to redirect to the first child, which is quite easy:

```
function  init() {
    parent::init();

    if($this->Children()->Count()){
        Controller::redirect($this->Children()->First()->AbsoluteLink());
    }
}
```

So it depends on you if you redirect manually by using default `RedirectorPage` or if you want something more fancier.